# Blazor says type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace '__Blazor...'

Tags: c#, generics, razor, blazor

I'm playing around with Blazor and trying to create a small Grid component. I'd like to pass through configurations via a simple object. The compiler throws the following error:

```
GridComponent.razor.g.cs(61, 254): [CS0234] The type or namespace name 'GridComponentConfig' does not exist in the namespace '__Blazor.Spa.Shared.Components.Grid' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

The razor and cs files are in the same directory.

```
<GridComponent data=@modules TItem="Module" Config=@GridComponentConfig></GridComponent>

@functions
{   
    protected GridComponentConfig GridComponentConfig = new GridComponentConfig
    {
        Columns = new List<string>
        {
            "id", "name", "description", "moduleroute"
        }
    };
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**GridComponent.razor**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components
@typeparam TItem

<table>
    <thead>
    <GridHeader Data=@Data Config=@Config></GridHeader>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>

@functions
{

    [Parameter]
    public IEnumerable<TItem> Data { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public GridComponentConfig Config { get; set; }

}
```

**GridHeader.razor**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components
@typeparam TItem

<tr>
    @foreach (string column in Config.Columns)
    {
        <td>@column</td>
    }
</tr>

@functions
{

    [Parameter]
    public IEnumerable<TItem> Data { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public GridComponentConfig Config { get; set; }

}
```

**GridComponentConfig.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Spa.Shared.Components.Grid
{
    public class GridComponentConfig
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> Columns { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Fix attempt 1:**

```
Pages/Components/Grid/GridComponent.razor
Pages/Components/Grid/GridHeader.razor
Common/GridComponentConfig.cs
```

The `@using`s fixed accordingly, example below, by Rider.

**GridComponent.razor**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components
@using Spa.Common
@typeparam TItem

<table>
    <thead>
    <GridHeader Data=@Data Config=@Config></GridHeader>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>

@functions
{

    [Parameter]
    protected IEnumerable<TItem> Data { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    protected GridComponentConfig Config { get; set; }

}
```

**GridHeader.razor**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components
@using Spa.Common
@typeparam TItem

<tr>
    @foreach (string column in Config.Columns)
    {
        <td>@column</td>
    }
</tr>

@functions
{

    [Parameter]
    public IEnumerable<TItem> Data { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public GridComponentConfig Config { get; set; }

}
```

**Result**:

```
GridComponent.razor.g.cs(57, 231): [CS0234] The type or namespace name 'Common' does not exist in the namespace '__Blazor.Spa' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

**Fix attempt 2:**

```
Pages/Components/Grid/GridComponent.razor
Pages/Components/Grid/GridHeader.razor
Pages/Components/Grid/GridComponentConfig.cs
```

The `@using`s fixed accordingly, example below, by Rider.

**GridComponent.razor**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components
@typeparam TItem

<table>
    <thead>
    <GridHeader Data=@Data Config=@Config></GridHeader>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>

@functions
{

    [Parameter]
    protected IEnumerable<TItem> Data { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    protected GridComponentConfig Config { get; set; }

}
```

**GridHeader.razor**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components
@typeparam TItem

<tr>
    @foreach (string column in Config.Columns)
    {
        <td>@column</td>
    }
</tr>

@functions
{

    [Parameter]
    public IEnumerable<TItem> Data { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public GridComponentConfig Config { get; set; }

}
```

**Result**:

```
GridComponent.razor.g.cs(56, 253): [CS0234] The type or namespace name 'GridComponentConfig' does not exist in the namespace '__Blazor.Spa.Pages.Components.Grid' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

**Update**:

- it seems I want something way different than Blazor/Razor can do. GridComponent can take the config object as parameter. But, if I want to pass the same config object to GridHeader component, then the compile error arises. I need to dig deeper.

Comment: _"The @usings fixed accordingly"_ - can you show those, just to be complete? Making a [mcve] would help.

Comment: @HenkHolterman thanks for your feedback. I added the files to my question.

Comment: Where do you use the GridComponent ? Show us the code. Show us how you pass values to its attribute properties. Provide a link to a complete sample of your app. Why do you insist on creating nested folders in your Pages folder, when your app is actually very simple. Heard of templated components ? I think you should use templated components.

Comment: Added the details. Creating folders help me separate code, as it grows I can split the app and create nuget packages, etc. [Kendo's Grid](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/) inspires me, and that I don't need to write JS code. I'm heading towards templated components, but I want pass config data to subcomponents and that is where this issue came up.